# asp:createuserwizard not showing all the fields

Tags: asp.net

I dragged and dropped the control, it shows all the inputs including 'Security Questions', but when I run it it's not showing the 'Security Questions' input.
Also, it won't fire the CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser event.

I need to use the control for the input validations and all but I don't want to use the built-in mechanism for the User Registration.
I need to call a wcf method instead. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the portion of web.config that defines settings for Membership provider has the property: `requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"`. 
Set this property to `true`

```
<membership>
<providers>
 <clear />
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
  connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
  enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
 requiresUniqueEmail="false" ...
</providers>
</membership>
```

Also, regarding the createduser event not being fired, follow below steps:

1.) Make sure you have set the  handler for CreatedUser event as below. Using: `OnCreatedUser`

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server"
     OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser>
        ....
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

2.) Also make sure you handle the event: `CreateUserError`. This event is raised  if there
    has  an error occurred while creating user.

```
  <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server"
          OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser"
          OnCreateUserError="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
           ...
        </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Your codebehind file will obviously containg your custom logic in above two event handlers as what you require .